# passwordToggle is removing the drawable in TextInputEditText

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I trying to create a password field with a lock icon on the left, and the passwordToggle icon on the right..... but I'm not able to show both icons at the same time.... how can I fix that?

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this one:**

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
          android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_20dp"
          android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_20dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8dp"
          android:theme="@style/EditTextHint"
          app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
          app:hintTextAppearance="@style/hint_appearance"
          app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

         <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/L_PASSWORD"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_20dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock"
        tools:ignore="TextFields" />
  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I have tried It working well :)

**o/p**

[image]

Comment: thank you very much...... It seems that I only needed to change the drawableLeft to drawableStart.

Comment: WelCome @A.mode